# Apex mechanism for determining if standard field is automatically calculated?

Tags: apex, describefieldresult

Is there any mechanism in apex for determining if a **standard** field's value on an sObject is automatically calculated by the platform? (Essentially a roll-up summary field.)

A custom roll up summary field will return `true` when calling the [`Schema.DescribeFieldResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) `.isCalculated()` method but the platform's standard summarized fields return `false`.

`Campaign.HierarchyAmountWonOpportunities` is one of these automatically calculated fields for instance.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Campaign.HierarchyAmountWonOpportunities.getDescribe();
system.debug(dfr);
```

The describe results for this field look like the list below, giving no indication that the platform automatically calculates this field's value.

```
getByteLength=0;
getCalculatedFormula=null;
getController=null;
getDefaultValue=null;
getDefaultValueFormula=null;
getDigits=0;
getFilteredLookupInfo=null;
getInlineHelpText=null;
getLabel=Total Value Won Opportunities in Hierarchy;
getLength=0;
getLocalName=HierarchyAmountWonOpportunities;
getMask=null;
getMaskType=null;
getName=HierarchyAmountWonOpportunities;
getPrecision=18;
getReferenceTargetField=null;
getRelationshipName=null;
getRelationshipOrder=null;
getScale=0;
getSoapType=DOUBLE;
getSobjectField=HierarchyAmountWonOpportunities;
getType=CURRENCY;
isAccessible=true;
isAutoNumber=false;
isCalculated=false;
isCascadeDelete=false;
isCaseSensitive=false;
isCreateable=false;
isCustom=false;
isDefaultedOnCreate=false;
isDependentPicklist=false;
isDeprecatedAndHidden=false;
isDisplayLocationInDecimal=false;
isEncrypted=false;
isExternalId=false;
isFilterable=true;
isGroupable=false;
isHighScaleNumber=false;
isHtmlFormatted=false;
isIdLookup=false;
isNameField=false;
isNamePointing=false;
isNillable=true;
isPermissionable=true;
isQueryByDistance=false;
isRestrictedDelete=false;
isSortable=true;
isUnique=false;
isUpdateable=false;
isWriteRequiresMasterRead=false;
```

Comment: Mark - Did you look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm ? field `Type`, and the various Summary... fields?

Answer (score 1):

If you call the REST API SObject Describe for Campaign I think you'll get a bit more info on your fields, including a Boolean value for "calculated".  Making use of that and the calculatedFormula field should allow you to determine it is a system calculated value and not a formula field.  Might check the updateable value too, Rollup Summary should be updateable: false.

Comment: Does calling the REST API produce a different result than the `isCalculated=false;` and `getCalculatedFormula=null` from the `DescribeFieldResult`? I would expect them to be identical.